# '70s or 80s TV episode with two-dimensional beings living on paper

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember a TV series similar to *The Twilight Zone* but mostly with children as main characters, and this episode where they find some sort of book or scroll inhabited by two-dimensional beings who look like Egyptians.
One human child - a boy, I think - watches the life of one of these creatures from the outside, and at a certain point helps him escape from his world by putting beside the book / scroll a single sheet of paper, over which the two-dimensional being slides and is then severed from his old world.

I can't remember if in this episode or another of the same series, there was a boy who travelled to another dimension / time ending in a egyptian-like society, where he met a girl. While running away with her he mounts a horse, something she had never seen before and loudly protests saying that "horses' backs are not made to sit upon".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part about the 2D people makes me remember a hungarian cartoon series, The [Mézga Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_M%C3%A9zga_Family). It was also aired in Italy, as "La famiglia Mezil".

In its second season (The Adventures of Aladár Mézga), this cartoon featured the son of the family who kept an inflatable starship under his bed, and used it to travel to different panets together with his talking dog.
In one of the [episodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ie8sElzJKH8&list=PLJd5jNMtTIE_9TgizAUnUebN4GduTDM9-), he visits a 2D planet and seems to live the same adventures you described in your question. The linked episode is in hungarian, but should be helpful enough for you to check if it is the show you're looking for.

Comment: That's it, THANK YOU!!! I didn't remember it was a cartoon, and the second part with the kids and the horse I'm sure it was with real actors so it must be from another show. I've been searching for this thing for like, 20 years!